# Field name to form part of object used in ng-messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form where the fields are generated dynamically, here is an example field:

```
<input ng-required="!question.answers[questionKey]" type="radio" ng-model="question.answers[questionKey]" value="{{ option.value }}"  name="question-{{ question.id }}" />
```

As you can see I am giving my field the name of `question-{{ question.id }}` this should give the value of question-1, question-2 etc.

I am now attempting to add some form validation to this field, how would access the property 'questionForm.question-1.$invalid' if the question-1 is dynamic?

Can I inject that into the following ng-messages directive somehow?

```
<div ng-messages="questionForm.name.$error">
    <p ng-message="minlength">Your name is too short.</p>
    <p ng-message="maxlength">Your name is too long.</p>
    <p ng-message="required">Your name is required.</p>
</div>
```

I hope that I am making sense?

Comment: What is it ng-messsages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`questionForm` is an object so you can access his properties like this `questionForm[question.id]` and get the errors for each question dynamically.

```
<div ng-messages="questionForm[question.id].$error">
    <p ng-message="minlength">Your name is too short.</p>
    <p ng-message="maxlength">Your name is too long.</p>
    <p ng-message="required">Your name is required.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did just discover this but Im going to accept you answer as it's exactly what I did. Thanks :)